# XCUIElementQuery does not find descendants of UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-testing

I have the following view hierarchy (verified with view debugger):

```
UIView "Page1"
  UIScrollView
    UILabel
    UISegmentedControl
    UIView
      UIView "Group1"
        UILabel
        UISegmentedControl "Selector1"

po app.otherElements["Page1"].otherElements["Group1"].hittable -> true
po app.otherElements["Page1"].otherElements["Group1"].segmentedControls.count -> 0
po app.otherElements["Page1"].otherElements["Group1"].descendantsMatchingType(XCUIElementType.Any).count -> 0
po app.otherElements["Page1"].descendantsMatchingType(XCUIElementType.Any).count -> 12
```

For me this looks as if XCUIElementQuery fails to dig into UIView.

Can somebody confirm or help me to identify my mistake.